# Seperate datetime table into array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime

I have a CSV table that I load in Matlab and looks as follows (see below).
I would like to separate the datetime column into separate values in the form of a double array, with 1 column for 'year', 1 column for 'month', and 1 column for 'day', something like:

```
2020  |  07  |  20
2020  |  07  |  20
```

The hour is not important. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: No Matlab on this machine to check, but doesn't `[y, m, d] = ymd(timestamp)` return the year, month and day series ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't when loading but once you have read in the data, you can follow @HighPerformanceMark:

```
% as a minimal example:
TimeStamp = datetime('now');

% split datetime
[y,m,d] = ymd(TimeStamp);
% build one matrix
Date = [y,m,d];
```